# Can I show a message on my Login page explaining that authorization had failed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a custom authorization scheme, and when a user isn't authorized, I return an `HttpUnauthorizedResult`. This causes the user to be redirected to the login page. Is it somehow possible, in the login page, to detect that it is being used because of an authorization failure and tell the user this? If so, how could I do this?

It would be a bonus if I could tell the user, "You need to log in as a user with x role to perform the action you requested", or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than return an HTTP 401, return a web page with the message you want, and a button to go to the login page.

Actually, you think that you are sending an Unauthorized response, but in reality ASP.NET is intercepting that HTTP 401 response and sending an HTTP 302 (Redirection) to your login page instead. So if you want a custom message, just redirect yourself to the page you want.

Cheers.

UPDATE:

If you create your own Authorize filter, you can define what happen if the user is not authorized/authenticated:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    readonly String _customError;

    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(String customError)
    {
        _customError = customError;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        filterContext.Controller.TempData["Error"] = _customError;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/yourErrorView");
    }
}
```

(Not tested)

That way you can use your attribute this way:

```
    [MyAuthorize("You are not authorized to see this thing")]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And then the user will be redirected to "~/Account/yourErrorView", and in the TempData you will find the custom error message.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better pass additional parameter which will describe the cause of error, for example:

> /Account/Login?error=4

and in the Login action check if error exists.

Besides you can store your error messages in different ways: session, cookie.

Comment: Problem is, as mentioned in @vtotola's answer, is that I am not redirecting to the the Login page. MVC is, so I'm looking for a hook into that redirect process where I could maybe pass an additional paramter.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionFilterAttribute instead of the AuthorizeFilterAttribute to point it to your error handling page.

```
public class RoleAuthorize: ActionFilterAttribute
    {

      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
             var controller = (YourController)filterContext.Controller;

        try
                {
                    if (!controller.CheckForRoleMethod())
                    {
                        throw new System.Security.SecurityException("Not Authorized!");
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Security.SecurityException secEx)
                {
                    if (secEx != null)
                    {
                        // I use TempData for errors like these. It's just me.
                        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = secEx.Message;
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "ErrorHandler" }, { "action", "Error" } });
                    }
                }     

        }

      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

You have to make a separate method on that controller being decorated to check if the cached user is Authorized or not like so:

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
     public bool CheckForRoleMethod(){
          // get formsauthentication details to retrieve credentials
          // return true if user has role else false
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why would you do that? The AuthorizeAttribute can check roles as well.